# Error When Publishing an NPM Package to Github Packages

Tags: github-package-registry, github-packages

I experiencing an error when trying to publish an NPM package to Github Packages.
Firstly, I created a Personal Access Token ("PAT") with `repo`, `write` and `read` scopes.

The I added a .npmrc file to my project with the following text:
`//npm.pkg.github.com/:_authToken=ghp_6O8Ho[rest-of-token]`

The, at the bash prompt, I entered the following (where `myaccountname` is the name of my Github account):
`npm login --scope=@myaccountname --auth-type=legacy --registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com`

I entered my username next.
Then, for the password, I pasted my PAT.
Then, for the email, I entered the primary email address for my account and it seemed to succeed:
`Logged in as myaccountname on https://npm.pkg.github.com/.`

However, when I entered `npm publish`, I got the following error:

> npm ERR! code ENEEDAUTH
> npm ERR! need auth This command requires you to be logged in.
> npm ERR! need auth You need to authorize this machine using `npm adduser`

Then running `npm add user` gave me a raft of whole new errors. But I cannot see that beinbg the right way to go anyway, as the Github doco does not mention that at all. It basically stops at `npm publish`, suggesting that it should have worked.

Oh and the repository url (https) is specified as the `repository` in package.json.

Can anyone see what I am missing?

Comment: Did you try setting [`publishConfig.registry`](https://docs.github.com/en/packages/working-with-a-github-packages-registry/working-with-the-npm-registry#publishing-a-package-using-publishconfig-in-the-packagejson-file)? Also, make sure that the name in package.json is scoped to your GH username

Comment: Your 2 suggestions appear to have worked. Just need to verify by consuming it now. Thanks.